# I am unable to create a table with unique list of variables created from case expression

Tags: sql

I want to create a table with 4 columns

- id1, id2, output1, output2 (at unique level)
- output1 and output2 are based on the below case expression

The output I am getting -

```
Plan   Formlry   drug1          drug2
P1       F1    drvd_fld_val      NULL
P1       F1       NULL        drvd_fld_val
```

I don't know how but due to some reasons it is showing 2 observations

I think it is unable to drop the drugname column and running the below case statement for both the drugs and thus duplicating the results

```
select ims_payer_plan_id, frmlry_id
      ,case when drugname = 'drug1' then drvd_fld_val  end as vimpat_access
      ,case when drugname = 'drug2' then drvd_fld_val  end as briviact_access 
 from  (
    select ims_payer_plan_id, frmlry_id, drugname, drvd_fld_val  
    from my_table
 )
```

The table i have here is unique at plan_id, frmlry_id, drugname and drvd_fld_val  level

The output I want -

```
Plan   Formlry   drug1         drug2
P1       F1    drvd_fld_val  drvd_fld_val
```

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation:

```
select ims_payer_plan_id, frmlry_id,
       max(case when drugname = 'drug1' then drvd_fld_val end) as vimpat_access
       max(case when drugname = 'drug2' then drvd_fld_val end) as briviact_access from my_table
group by ims_payer_plan_id, frmlry_id;
```